# Find a point in a polygon using Sequelize and postgis

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, polygon, postgis

I'm using sequelize and postgis, and I have a table device with a column coord with type GEOMETRY('POINT').

when an insert a new device, in my columns coord value I use this:

coord = { 
            type: 'Point', 
            coordinates: [lng,lat],
            crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'EPSG:3857'}}
        }

and it's ok for now.

Next, I need to find all devices in an area limited by a polygon

example in pseudo-code:

device coord is (lng1, lat1)

my poligon is [lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4, ...]

how can I do this query using sequelize?

sequelize 4.41.0
node v9.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sequelize.fn()` to call the postgis function `st_within()`, which basically returns true if the first geometry argument is completely inside the second geometry argument. Here is an example

```
Device.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('ST_Within', sequelize.col('coord'), sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', 'POLYGON((lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4, ...))')),
    true
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sequelize.fn() to call postgis st_within() function

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html

https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/sequelize/#fnfn-args-sequelizefn