# Sequelize findAll with calculated column

Tags: sequelize.js, geojson

I am trying to find out if a certain GEOMETRY is in bounding POLYGON.  I found this answer ([Find a point in a polygon using Sequelize and postgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324917/find-a-point-in-a-polygon-using-sequelize-and-postgis)) but it only describes how to do a single where check.

I need to create a complex where clause.  How do use a complex where clause using ST_Within?

Answer from linked question

```
Device.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('ST_Within', sequelize.col('coord'), sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', 'POLYGON((lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4, ...))')),
    true
  )
});
```

I have tried to add this value to the findAll attributes:

```
Device.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [
      sequelize.fn('ST_Within', sequelize.col('coord'), sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', 'POLYGON((lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4, ...))')),
        true
      ), 
      'contains'
    ]
  ]
  where: {
    name: "cellphone",
    contains: true
  }
});
```

But I get an error about contains not existing in the Device table.  I know it does not exist, I calculated it in the attributes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply combine this geometric condition with other conditions using `Op.and`/`Op.or` (depending on what you need to get):

```js
Device.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('ST_Within', sequelize.col('coord'), sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', 'POLYGON((lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4, ...))')),
    true
  ),
  {
     name: "cellphone"
  }
    ]
  }
});
```